# getting error when executing the selenium testng tests in jenkins job in centos7.6 VM

Tags: selenium, testng

I am able to execute the tests in windows properly, but when I create the jenkins job in centos7.6 VM and the jenkins job console output shows the below error.

This is what I have defined in the code:

```
{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "/tmp/chromedriver_linux");
    }
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Below is the error:

```
enter code here Test01(com.training.multi.browser.testing.MultiTests)  Time elapsed: 2.164 sec  <<< FAILURE!
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
      (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b07dc18a74666574f19176731995c-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1155}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 1.66 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
    System info: host: 'localhost.localdomain', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_222'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at com.training.multi.base.BaseTest.getDriver(BaseTest.java:19)
    at com.training.multi.browser.testing.MultiTests.Test01(MultiTests.java:36)`
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of additional steps you need to take in order to make test running in Jenkins on Linux via setting extra [ChromeOptions](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

1. Make sure to add [`--headless`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) argument as systems running Jenkins normally don't have GUI
2. If you're running Jenkins as [`root` user](https://geek-university.com/linux/root-account/) you also need to set [`--no-sandbox`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638180) option

Something like:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--headless", "--no-sandbox"));
options.setBinary("/path/to/chromedriver");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Also make sure that the user has appropriate permissions in order to launch the `chromedriver` binary, if not - grant them using [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command like:

```
chmod +x /tmp/chromedriver_linux
```

More information: [How to use Jenkins pipeline to launch Selenium tests](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/jenkins-pipeline-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
```

This error is caused when there is incompatibility in version of chrome and chromedriver you are using. Upgrade chrome browser on your centos machine and download the new chrome version compatible chromedriver.

Comment: I am already using the latest version of chromedriver file. And also installed the latest version of chrome in centos using yum -y install chromium. Does nt it get the latest version of chrome in centos? if not please let me know.